# Cmd+Plus shortcut not recognised on MacBook

Tags: c++, qt

I want to capture shortcut Cmd+Plus to do something (zoom something). But as I found this does not work on MacBooks because Cmd+Plus has to be pressed with holding Shift key. So instead of Cmd+Plus I got Cmd+Shift+=. What is interesting: on Windows and Linux everything works as expected (Ctrl instead of Cmd, of course).

A piece of code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override {
        qInfo() << event->key() << event->modifiers();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

When I press Cmd+Plus (with holding Shift), this code outputs `61 QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifier>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier)` on my MacBook. Note that 61 is decadic number of '='.

This code outputs `43 QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifier>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier)` on Windows and Linux notebooks which also require pressing Shift. But here 43 is '+'. Which is correct.

Well, how to capture Cmd+Plus then? On all platforms (equiv. Ctrl instead of Cmd on Windows and Linux), on all possible national keyboard layouts?

Comment: MacOS has a bit different philosophy on keyboard shortcuts. Try `cmd`+... .

Comment: @Marek R Of course, I know and I meant pressing Cmd. ControlModifier in Qt represents Cmd key on Mac. You can see it from the output of the code which I provided. I updated the text to be more clear.

The problem however is not with Cmd vs Ctrl. It is with Plus vs Shift+=.

Comment: Which version of MacOS? https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74257